# .HTACCESS Subdomain instead of .CONF Subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, domain, .htaccess, subdomain

I have 3 sample domains and would like to converting this .conf to .htaccess so that I don't have to restart my Apache all the time once I've updated my subdomain settings.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost    *:80>
    ServerName www.myserver.com
    DocumentRoot /www
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost    *:80>
    ServerName marhazk.myserver.com
    DocumentRoot /www/marhazk.com
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost    *:80>
    ServerName perfectworld.myserver.com
    DocumentRoot /www/perfectworld.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Any idea how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to use virtual host settings in htacess files but you might want to take a look to Apache Mass Virtual Host settings, this allow to have dynamic mapping between servername and documentroot 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't put VirutalHost directives in a .htaccess file. How would Apache even know where to look for the .htaccess file in the first place?

On the [Apache help pages](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost), notice that the context is limited to the server config only.